# Android firebase writing data loads another fragment or reload activity with these fragments

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created activity "home" with bottom nav containing 2 fragments: "lecturerHome" and "lecturerSubject". I added to "lecturerSubject" listview connected to Firebase which shows years and EditText with button to add years to listview. The problem is that when I click button, firebase add everything goes well, new item shows in listview but suddenly, probably "home" activity, starts to reload. And I land on main view of activity which is "lecturerHome". How can I stop this to happen?

```
package com.example.studentapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.time.Year;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;

public class lecturerSubject extends Fragment {
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

private RelativeLayout layout;
private ListView yearsList, groupsList;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private TextView addYear, addNextYear, addGroup, addNextGroup;
private Button addYearBtn, addGroupBtn;
private EditText addYearEdit;
private String newYear, nextYear;
private ArrayList<String> yearsArr = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> groupsArr = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapterGroups;
private lecturerSubject lecturerSubject;
private boolean firstYear, firstGroup;

SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

public lecturerSubject() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static lecturerSubject newInstance() {
    lecturerSubject fragment = new lecturerSubject();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("com.example.studentApp", 0);
    editor = pref.edit();

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
    lecturerSubject = new lecturerSubject();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lecturer_subject, container, false);

    layout = v.findViewById(R.id.lecturer_subject_layout);
    addYear = v.findViewById(R.id.add_year_text);
    addNextYear = v.findViewById(R.id.add_next_year_text);
    addGroup = v.findViewById(R.id.add_group_text);
    addNextGroup = v.findViewById(R.id.add_next_group_text);
    addYearBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.add_year_button);
    addGroupBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.add_group_button);
    addYearEdit = v.findViewById(R.id.add_year_edit);
    progressBar = v.findViewById(R.id.add_progress);
    yearsList = v.findViewById(R.id.years_list);
    groupsList = v.findViewById(R.id.group_list);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, yearsArr);
    yearsList.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapterGroups = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, groupsArr);
    groupsList.setAdapter(adapterGroups);

    firstYear = pref.getBoolean("firstYear", false);

    if(firstYear){
        addYear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else{
        addNextYear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    addYearBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            yearsList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            newYear = addYearEdit.getText().toString();

            mDatabase.child("year").child(newYear).setValue(" ").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        showMessage("OK");
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

After writing anything in editText and clicking button firebase writes data well and after task is completed it reloads to lecturerHome fragment (or reloads activity).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add the code the produces this behaviour.

Comment: Please *don't* use the same colours for your background and the bottom navigation bar. This decreases the text's readability and makes it hard to differentiate between the background and the bottom navigation bar.

Comment: @Edric yeah true, it's not well prepared. I'm doing some project to pass subject and mostly need good logic. If I have some time I will change that ;)